# Weird "Error 404 (Not Found)!!1"

Tags: iis, proxy, apache2

I hosted a site in an Apache2 server that's behind an IIS proxy, everything managed by one of my customers.

My customer told me he just redirects all requests to https://estudios.hbritanico.com.ar to the Apache server's port 443, and it seems ok, but some times I get a weird 404 error message comming from Google when I call https://estudios.hbritanico.com.ar/im/#/.

This doesn't happen always, but after reloading that page many times and clearing the browser's cache, also by looking at network tab in developer's tools.

This is the error I get:
[image: Google's 404 (Not Found)!!1]

As you can see that doesn't look correct, I could expect a plain 404 comming from Apache when a resource cannot be found, but never a message from Google...

Can someone help me find a solution for this?, my customer suspects this can be related to the SSL certificate used on this site, but I doubt it, because if that is the case an error should be raised everytime I try to load that page.

Comment: Read IIS log files to see if you can find records that match the 404s. Then their sub-status should tell https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: It turns out there's something related to the DNS. In /etc/resolv.conf there was an `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (Google's DNS), I replaced with the customer's one and it's working perfectly right now.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there's something related to the DNS. In /etc/resolv.conf there was an nameserver 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS), I replaced with the customer's one and it's working perfectly right now.

Comment: Maybe you can check the DNS query results for the two DNS servers, for the same domain estudios.hbritanico.com.ar. That should reveal more information (like Google DNS returns an invalid address) to close the investigation. Of course, you already got the answer.